# Python: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a program in Python however I am getting the following error when I run it through the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packetSniffer.py", line 120, in <module>
    main()
  File "packetSniffer.py", line 27, in main
    (version, headerLength, timeToLive, protocol, source, target, data) = ip(data)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 7)
```

However I am doing everything the proper way (I am assuming because I don't see anything wrong with my code). I hope a fresh set of eyes will be able to spot my issue.

Here is my entire program:

```
import struct
import textwrap
import socket

TAB_1 = '\t - '
TAB_2 = '\t\t - '
TAB_3 = '\t\t\t - '
TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t - '

DATA_TAB_1 = '\t   '
DATA_TAB_2 = '\t\t   '
DATA_TAB_3 = '\t\t\t   '
DATA_TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t   '


def main():
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))

    while True:
        rawData, address = connection.recvfrom(65535)
        reciever_mac, sender_mac, ethernetProtocol, data = ethernet_frame(rawData)
        print('\nEthernet Frame: ')
        print(TAB_1 + 'Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}'.format(reciever_mac, sender_mac, ethernetProtocol))

        #Make sure you are using Ethernet protocol 8
        if ethernetProtocol == 8:
            (version, headerLength, timeToLive, protocol, source, target, data) = ip(data)
            print(TAB_1 + 'IP Packet:')
            print(TAB_2 + 'Version: {}, Header Length: {}, TTL: {}'.format(version, headerLength, timeToLive))
            print(TAB_2 + 'Protocol: {}, Source: {}, Target: {}'.format(protocol, source, target))

            if protocol == 1:
                icmpType, code, checkSum, data = icmpPackets(data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'ICMP Packet:')
                print(TAB_2 + 'Type: {}, Code: {}, Checksum: {},'.format(icmpType, code, checkSum))
                print(TAB_2 + 'Data:')
                print(formatMultiLine(DATA_TAB_3, data))

            elif protocol == 6:
                (sourcePort, destinationPort, sequence, acknowledgement, flagURG, flagACK, flagPSH, flagRST, flagSYN, flagFIN, data) = tcpSegment(data)
                print(TAB_2 + 'Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}'.format(sourcePort, destinationPort))
                print(TAB_2 + 'Sequence: {}, Acknowledgment: {}'.format(sequence, acknowledgement))
                print(TAB_2 + 'Flags:')
                print(TAB_3 + 'URG: {}, ACK: {}, PSH: {}'.format(flagURG, flagACK, flagPSH))
                print(TAB_3 + 'RST: {}, SYN: {}, FIN:{}'.format(flagRST, flagSYN, flagSYN))
                print(formatMultiLine(DATA_TAB_3, data))

            elif protocol == 17:
                (sourcePort, destinationPort, length, data) = udpSegment(data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'UDP Segment:')
                print(TAB_2 + 'Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}, Length: {}'.format(sourcePort, destinationPort, length))

            else:
                print(TAB_1 + 'Other IPv4 Data:')
                print(formatMultiLine(DATA_TAB_2, data))

        else:
            print('Ethernet Data:')
            print(formatMultiLine(DATA_TAB_1, data))


# Unpack ethernet frame
def ethernet_frame(data):
    reciever_mac, sender_mac, protocol = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data[:14])
    return getMacAddress(reciever_mac), getMacAddress(sender_mac), socket.htons(protocol), data[14:]

# Convert the Mac address from the jumbled up form from above into human readable format
def getMacAddress(bytesAddress):
    bytesString = map('{:02x}'.format, bytesAddress)
    macAddress = ':'.join(bytesString).upper()
    return macAddress

#Unpack IP header data
def ip_packet(data):
    versionHeaderLength = data[0]
    version = versionHeaderLength >> 4
    headerLength = (versionHeaderLength & 15) * 4

    timeToLive, protocol, source, target = struct.unpack('! 8x B B  2x 4s 4s', data[:20])
    return version, headerLength, timeToLive, protocol, ip(source), ip(target), data[headerLength:]

#Returns properly formatted IP address
def ip(address):
    return '.'.join(map(str, address))

#Unpack ICMP packets
def icmpPackets(data):
    icmpType, code, checkSum = struct.unpack('! B B H', data[:4])
    return icmpType, code, checkSum, data[4:]

#Unpack TCP segments:
def tcpSegment(data):
    (sourcePort, destinationPort, sequence, acknowledgement, offsetReservedFlags) = struct.unpack('! H H L L H', data[:14])
    offset = (offsetReservedFlags >> 12) * 4

    flagURG = (offsetReservedFlags & 32) >> 5
    flagACK = (offsetReservedFlags & 16) >> 4
    flagPSH = (offsetReservedFlags & 8) >> 3
    flagRST = (offsetReservedFlags & 4) >> 2
    flagSYN = (offsetReservedFlags & 2) >> 1
    flagFIN = offsetReservedFlags & 1

    return sourcePort, destinationPort, sequence, acknowledgement, flagURG, flagACK, flagPSH, flagRST, flagSYN, flagFIN, data[offset:]

#Unpack UDP segments:
def udpSegment(data):
    sourcePort, destinationPort, size = struct.unpack('! H H 2x H', data[:8])
    return sourcePort, destinationPort, size, data[8:]

#Breaks down and formats large, multi-lined data
def formatMultiLine(prefix, string, size = 80):
    size -= len(prefix)
    if isinstance(string, bytes):
        string = ''.join(r'\x{:02X}'.format(byte) for byte in string)
        if size % 2:
            size -= 1

    return '\n'.join([prefix + line for line in textwrap.wrap(string, size)])

main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So..what is `ip(data)` ?

Comment: That's just another function I have...would you like me to post my entire program code?

Comment: Should we use our crystal ball to figure out what `ip()` returns instead?

Comment: Just post the code related to `ip` function...wanna say what is its return ?

Comment: Edited...also ip just returns: '.'.join(map(str, address))

Comment: If that's all that `ip()` returns then why do you think you can extract all the information from it that you're trying to?

Comment: How do you expect to unpack a string into 7 variables?  You _can_ do that if the length of the string is exactly 7, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before the errant line:

```
(version, headerLength, timeToLive, protocol, source, target, data) = ip(data)
```

you should place the following:

```
print(data)
print(ip(data))
```

The output of that should then show you *exactly* what the problem is - this is Debugging 101 stuff, it's almost *always* better to have more information than less when trying to debug your code.

In this case, it's almost guaranteed that `ip(data)` will be returning a number of items *other* than seven.

Comment: That displays more information, but it is all unreadable information haha

Comment: Figured it out eventually...it was a typo haha

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be ip(data) returns a seq with more than 7 elems.
Try this:

```
(version, headerLength, timeToLive, protocol, source, target, data) = ip(data)[:7]
```

Comment: That doesn't give me the error but it doesn't give me the data I am looking for either

Comment: What i can do for you is to help you to find out your problem.You need to find what you need from "ip(data)" by yourself.Why do i know what you needs?

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is yours `ip` function only return a string, but you want to extract a bunch of stuff that it simple can't be extracted by just unpacking, you need to redefine the `ip` function to return all that stuff or change how you use it.

By the way, there is a way to in case of a larger sequence put all the remaining stuff by using `*` in one, and only one, of the variables in your unpack list python make some calculation such that everyone get a part od the data that is going to be unpacked

```
>>> test="255.255.255.255"
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,*h=test
>>> a
'2'
>>> b
'5'
>>> c
'5'
>>> d
'.'
>>> h
['.', '2', '5', '5', '.', '2', '5', '5']
>>> 
>>> *a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h=test
>>> a
['2', '5', '5', '.', '2', '5', '5', '.']
>>> b
'2'
>>> c
'5'
>>> a,b,*c,d,e,f,g,h=test
>>> a
'2'
>>> b
'5'
>>> c
['5', '.', '2', '5', '5', '.', '2', '5']
>>> d
'5'
>>>
```

and as you can see, unpacking a string will only give you a character...